# to access json array inside json array

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to build quiz game with the help of JSON. In my first question only I'm facing problem since I'm using the JSON for the first time.

JSON file is :

```
"Question1": [{
  "name": "here will be first question ",
  "answer":"correct answer",
  "wrongans" : [
      "wronganswer optionA",
      "wronganswer optionB",
      "wronganswer optionC"
  ]
}],
```

next i'm parsing the JSON to Java object, so one method I have created:

```
public static void loadJsonLevels(String fileName, String ques) {
    JsonValue jsonValue = new   JsonReader().parse(Gdx.files.internal(fileName));
    JsonValue nameValue = jsonValue.get("Question1");

    if (ques.equals("Question1")) {
        for (JsonValue value : nameValue.iterator()) {
            question1.add(new QuestionBase());               
            question1.get(question1.size()-1).setQuesname(value.getString("name"));
            question1.get(question1.size()-1).setCorrectAns(value.getString("answer"));
        }
    }
}
```

was able to access till here , next i want to access "wrongans" , stored in json which is array . I have created a separate class for QuestionBase, which is

```
public class QuestionBase {

    public String quesname;

    public String correctAns;

    public String[] wronganswers;

}
```

have created the object of the class QuestionBase i.e

```
public static ArrayList<QuestionBase> question1 = new ArrayList<QuestionBase>();
```

this `question1` is used inside the method `loadJsonLevels()`, finding hard to access the "wrongans", it will really helpful if anyone gives the idea how to proceed further or changes I should make.

Comment: Why is the array named "Question1" instead of "questions", for example? The first object is always question1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get String array in this way :

```
JsonValue stringValue=value.get("wrongans");
question1.get(question1.size()-1).setWronganswers(stringValue.asStringArray());
```

Check value in Array :

```
for (String wrongAns:question1.get(question1.size()-1).getWronganswers())
     System.out.println("WRONG ANS : "+wrongAns);
```

---

In another way you can Keep your question in separate `.json` file, like

**1stQues.json**

```
{
    "quesname": "here will be first question ",
    "correctAns":"correct answer is what",
    "wronganswers" : [

       "wronganswer optionA",
       "wronganswer optionB",
       "wronganswer optionC"
    ]
}
```

And then create object from `.json` file

```
Json json=new Json();
QuestionBase questionBase=json.fromJson(QuestionBase.class,Gdx.files.internal("1stQues.json"));

for (String wrongAns:questionBase.getWronganswers())
    System.out.println("Wrong ans in 1st ques : "+wrongAns);
```

Comment: Thank you its working perfectly , i tried with with first one .

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Gson JSON Parser](https://github.com/google/gson) -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

//Parse json into a YourJavaClass object.
YourJavaClass yourJavaClass= gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, YourJavaClass.class);
```

Here you can find complete example -> [Parsing objects in a json array with gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050803/parsing-objects-in-a-json-array-with-gson/45050928?noredirect=1#comment77082687_45050928)

Comment: Except this requires the json to be in a different  format

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONObject("Question1");
if (jsonarray.length() != 0) {
  for(int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    content = jsonarray.getJsonObject(i).getString("name");
    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonarray.getJSONArray("wronganswers");
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
      a1 = jsonArray1.getString(i);
    }
  }
}
```